# Просмотр двоичного содержимого файла

Tags: кодировка, text, notepad++

Как можно увидеть двоичное содержимое файла с помощью стандартных приложений, например, *Notepad++*?

Например, у меня есть текст

> 漢字

и после сохранения в соответствующей кодировке (*UTF-8*) я хочу увидеть двоичное представление этих символов:

> 11100110 10111100 10100010 11100101 10101101 10010111

Какой наиболее лёгкий способ для этого существует?

Comment: Лично я испоьзую для таких целей Far Manager, либо также какой нибудь hex editor. Полагаю, во встроенном просмотрщике практически любого файлового менеджера можно найти эту функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в стандартной сборке это "Plugins -> converter -> Conversion Panel", правда конвертит по одному символу, не очень удобно